# Linear Differential Equation but with piece wise function ( Cant Solve )

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a continuous solution satisfying the DE
$$y' + y = f(x),$$

where

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}
1, &  0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
-1, &  x>1\text{.}\end{cases}\\
y(0)&=1\end{align}

I am new to the forum so sorry guys for the format mistakes but really looking for the solution of this desperately & the 2nd question is

$$y' + 2xy = f(x),$$

where

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}
x, &  0 \leq x \leq 3 \\
0, &  x >1\text{.}\end{cases}\\
y(0)&=2\end{align}

**These questions are in my Book ODE by Zillls 3rd Edition Exercise 2.5 . Question number 57,58**

Kindly help me out mates , i will be thankfull

Comment: Which are your efforts? Are you allowed to use Fourier transform, Laplace transform, or something similar?

Comment: Nope we have to find the solution using Integrating factor

Comment: Though i have solved Linear , Exact , Bernouli's etc but for this i have scrolled the web but cant find any appropriate way to solve it , there is a similar question solved by the community member but again having some problems in it

Comment: A similar solution

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319227/first-order-linear-ordinary-differential-equation-with-piecewise-constant-source

Answer (score 1):

**First equation**
(**Update** Fixed, thanks to RodrigodeAzevedo)

Consider $0 \leq x \leq 1$, then:
$$\begin{cases}
y' + y = 1 \\
y(0) = 1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow y(x) = 1 \Rightarrow y(1) = 1.$$

Now, solve the differential equation for $x > 1$:
$$\begin{cases}
y' + y = -1 \\
y(1) = 1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow y(t) = 2e^{-x+1} - 1.$$

Finally:
$$y(x) = \begin{cases}1 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
2e^{-x+1} - 1 & x > 1.
\end{cases}$$

Notice that for $x=1$, this function is continuous.

**Second equation**

This can be solved by using the very standard method of [Separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Consider $0 \leq x \leq 3$, then:
$$\begin{cases}
y' + 2xy = x \\
y(0) = 2
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = x(1-2y) \Rightarrow \\
\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)}\frac{dy}{1-2y} = \int_0^x s ds \Rightarrow \\
\int_{2}^{y(x)}\frac{dy}{1-2y} = \int_0^x s ds \Rightarrow \\
-\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\left(y(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right) - \log\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{2}x^2 \Rightarrow \\
y(x) = \frac{3e^{-x^2}+1}{2} \Rightarrow 
y(3) = \frac{3e^{-9}+1}{2}.$$

Now consider $x > 3$, then:
$$\begin{cases}
y' + 2xy = 0 \\
y(3) = \frac{3e^{-9}+1}{2}
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -2xy \Rightarrow \\
\int_{y(3)}^{y(x)}\frac{dy}{y} = -2\int_0^x s ds \Rightarrow \\
\int_{\frac{3e^{-9}+1}{2}}^{y(x)}\frac{dy}{y} = -2\int_3^x s ds \Rightarrow \\
\log\left(y(x)\right) - \log\left(\frac{3e^{-9}+1}{2}\right) = -(x^2-9) \Rightarrow \\
y(x) = \frac{3e^{-9}+1}{2}e^{-(x^2-9)}$$

Again, this is continuous for $x=3$.

Comment: The solution over $[0,1]$ is incorrect.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks a lot for the comment. Anyway, I don't catch your point. Can you kindly explain why it does not work?

Comment: Your solution does not satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks a lot again, I did a mistake....

Comment: Thanks for the solution #candyman :))

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this , Its quite difficult how you solve the Equation 2 !

Comment: @Skphero equation 2 is solved using a very standard method, the Separation of Variables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables)